# Slow internet connection with TP-Link AV500 Mini Powerline Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I wanted to connect a PC without Wi-Fi adapter to the internet and I used a Powerline Adapter I had. I expected it to go faster than my laptop connected to the internet with the Wi-Fi adapter but it goes slower and I want to know why is that and what could I do to improve the speed. This is the device:
[image]
The cables are both CAT 5. The Powerline is connected directly to a plug in both ends not to a plug extension. The speed test I did in the pc with the Powerline connection gave a 19 ms ping, 9 mb up and down. The Wi-Fi connection gave a 19 ms ping with 100 mb up and down which is what I should get. I don't know what would give a better internet connection. Should I buy a better Powerline, buy a wireless adapter for the pc or pay somebody to put an Ethernet socket in the room to connect the pc? If I buy a new Powerline which could I buy to have 100mb up and down and no random disconnections like the current one? And why does the laptop go faster than the PC?

Comment: Have you tried a different patch cable?

Comment: My guess would be different electrical circuits - possibly going across an RCD or 2, which can weaken the signal. An Ethernet socket is the way to go if its affordable and practical - this can give the fastest speeds, greatest reliability and best future proofing.

Comment: What _other_ powerline adapters do you have (i.e. what's on the other end of the connection)? What link speeds are reported by TP-Link's tpPLC software or by `plctool -m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main possibilities:

- the electrical pathway between these two *particular* outlets isn't optimal for use with powerline adapters.
- faulty powerline adapters.

To rule out a bandwidth problem caused by the house wiring, give the powerline adapters the best chance of success by plugging them in side by side into two receptacles in the same power outlet, then run another speed test.

This will temporarily bypass the breaker panel and all wiring in the walls:

[image]

If the speed improves significantly, then your house wiring was impeding the performance of your powerline adapters and you should experiment with different outlets to find a combination that supports increased network bandwidth.

If the speed remains the same, then there is a problem with the adapters themselves and you should consider replacing them.

Comment: I used to be a big proponent of powerline Ethernet adapters but I eventually realized how prone to failure they can be and now strongly advise people to run Ethernet instead if possible.

Comment: I saw there was a better connection in another plug so I moved the computer there. Now I have a 95mb up and down, so the problem maybe was the noise in the electrical pathway. Now I have the problem of the adapter randomly disconnecting from time to time.

Comment: Random disconnects that require reboots of the adapters is the reason I switched from powerline adapters to regular Ethernet, despite the inconvenience of Ethernet installation. You might be able to solve the instability problem by replacing the adapters with new ones or a different model but there's no guarantee.